# Correct way to pass python bytes to Presto query (and retrieve and decode those bytes)

Tags: python, numpy, byte, presto

I want to store numpy bytes with Presto.  I have the following

```
import numpy as np
array = np.array([1.0,3.4,5.1])
these_bytes = array.tobytes()
```

and then I want to store them in presto, using a query like this

```
query = f"INSERT INTO some_table VALUES ({these_bytes},'2021-03-11')"
```

where the {these_bytes} entry is a VARBINARY column.  Of course, presto gives the error 'b' not recognized as "these_bytes" is actually a bytes object and not a string so it looks like b'...'. It seems I should then be decoding this object and storing the decoding...  What is the correct way to store python binary bytes with presto, and then will there be any transformations required upon retrieval?  Assume my python presto client just passes the query without doing additional transformations.

The expanded fstring looks like

```
INSERT INTO imu_test_table_1000 VALUES (b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf0?333333\x0b@ffffff\x14@','2021-03-11')
```

which is not right.

Comment: The problem here is that f-strings implicitly convert anything in `{}` to a `str`. Take a look at `these_bytes` vs `query`, all of the \s are escaped in `query`.

Comment: Try using the parameter binding provided by whatever driver you're using to insert the bytes into the query, this strategy usually accounts for marshalling the datatype.

Comment: Did you try to use a bf-string? bf"INSERT ... {these_bytes}..."

Comment: Scratch that, there is no bf-string. I was thinking of the rf-string.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need these_bytes.decode() (although, if you have unprintable characters that is probably going to be an issue and will fail). You would also need to know what encoding your client wants the characters to be in (utf8, utf16, etc.). If you don't know that, then I would be confused how your client interprets what characters it is sent, or why it wants to receive characters instead of bytes.

In general, most data transferring is done in bytes (I don't know about your particular client). This would include things like subprocessing, sockets, requests, etc. all use bytes (since this is what computers talk in). A byte string can contain any byte value and is simply data ready for transfer. A string is a collection of characters (each character could be made of several bytes in memory) which represents some kind of human writing/text. In particular, not every byte string can be encoded into characters, hence str.decode() will not work unless you specifically have bytes for the utf8 code-set.

If you want to combine arbitray bytes (not representing any particular format or characters), then you CANNOT use a string; use must keep the data in a byte array. Like

```
query = b"INSERT INTO some_table VALUES (" + these_bytes + b",'2021-03-11')"
```